# Issue with custom report that shows all users registered for event in last 2 years but not this year

Tags: php, reports, custom-reports

I am using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.6.28.

I am trying to create a report that will display all of the users who registered for an event in 2015 and 2016, but not yet in 2017.  I have the report working to the point of displaying all who registered in 2015, 16, and 17.  I am not sure how to go about removing those who have not registered in 2017.  The idea I've been trying is to create an array of contact_ids that are registered in 2017, and then use that array in the WHERE clause, to only select rows that do not contain that contact_id.  It is still displaying users who have registered in 2017, though.

I am running this query in the where() function in the report php file.

Here are the contents of the where() function:

```
$sql = "SELECT {$this->_aliases['civicrm_participant']}.contact_id, 
{$this->_aliases['civicrm_participant']}.register_date 
FROM civicrm_participant {$this->_aliases['civicrm_participant']}";

$dao = CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery($sql);
$i = 0;
$registered = array();

while($dao->fetch()) {
    if (strpos($dao->civicrm_participant_register_date, '2017') !== false ) 
    {
        $registered[$i] = $dao->civicrm_participant_contact_id;
        $i++;
    }
 }

$this->_where = "WHERE ({$this->_aliases['civicrm_event']}.title = 'SF Open 
Studios 2017' 
OR {$this->_aliases['civicrm_event']}.title = 'SF Open Studios 2016' 
OR {$this->_aliases['civicrm_event']}.title = 'SF Open Studios 2015') 
AND {$this->_aliases['civicrm_participant']}.contact_id 
NOT IN ( '" . implode($registered, "', '") . "' )";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished similar results to what you are looking for by doing the following.

- I created a smart group for all those who have registered for the current event (2017)
- I then used the participant report filters to include all registrants from the previous events (2015 & 2016)
- I then added a filter to exclude any members of the smart group for the current event.

I do all this using the report filters on the standard participant report but you could probably apply similar filters to a custom report. I also use the current event registrant smart group to exclude folks who have already registered from promotional mailings. It comes in handy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know, is there a way to remove duplicates? I have a report now that shows those who registered in 15/16 and not 17, but it is showing anyone who registered in both 15 and 16 twice

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the excellent [Summary Fields extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) which gives you the "Date of the last attended event field", and you should then be able to use relative date filters to get what you required, or an include/exclude group.

Comment: I went with the other posted solution before I saw your comment, but I will have to check that out for the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know, is there a way to remove duplicates?  I have a report now that shows those who registered in 15/16 and not 17, but it is showing anyone who registered in both 15 and 16 twice.

Comment: Not sure if you are asking this having set up Summary Fields or not.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution might be to use Drupal Views instead of Report : Views provides easy filtering features.